# Are there listing sites or databases that include or even focus on European manga authors?

Tags: resources, mangaka, europe

I am looking for European manga authors for the sake of a study, not a reading recommendation. I am currently investigating the European arts market.

How can I find out this information?

Comment: Could you perhaps specify what you mean by European manga authors? Are you looking for information on Europeans that work/create manga from Europe for Japanese studios? Or European studio's producing such works? Perhaps something else all together?

Comment: Hello, and apologies for the late answer. I mean European authors who publish their work from Europe. Whether the publisher is European or Japanese, it really does not mater. Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 2):

The anime database aniSearch also features manga and includes countries outside of Asia.

[Filtered for France as country of origin](https://www.anisearch.com/manga/index?char=all&origin=7&sort=title&order=asc&view=4&limit=20&title=en,fr,de,it,pl,ru,es,tr&titlex=1,2)

You can filter for other countries by going to *Search Filter>Basics>Country of Origin*.

Information about the author isn't always present, though. But you can research the information and add it to the database.